# Android PopUp window behing view

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

Is there a way to "inflate" the PopupWindow inside View ? I mean that if I have Button and I want the popup window(for example the popupwindow is above the Button) to be in the same layout as Button i.e. if the Button is in ScrollView, when the button not visible (it is scrolled above), then the popup be not visible too. And for example I don't want part the popup go outside from the DialogFragment if it is created from this dialog fragment. Is there any way to achieve this ? 
Thanks in advance.